# Why doesn't Powerpoint's Slide Show view show the latest changes made on a Master layout shape's text property?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, slideshow

**Background**

I have a countdown timer created with 2 shapes in a **custom layout** slide in Master layout. The first one, `pieShape`, is created using the Powerpoint's Pie shape and the second one, `ovalShape`, is created using the Oval shape.

[image]

I have a piece of code in my VSTO C# add-in that regularly updates the `pieShape.Adjustments[2]` property and `ovalShape.TextFrame2.TextFrange.Text` property every 1 second using a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` class. Changes in `ovalShape.TextFrame2.TextFrange.Text` should cause a number to change

**Problem**

The changes in `ovalShape.TextFrame2.TextFrange.Text` is not reflected in slideshow view e.g., only `pieShape` is updated, not `ovalShape`. However, it is reflected **outside** of slideshow view.

How the timer behaves when viewing in SlideShow view. (Only `pieShape` is updated)
[image]

How the timer behaves when viewing **outside of** SlideShow. (Correct behaviour)
[image]

Why doesn't Powerpoint's Slide Show view show the latest changes made on a shape's text property whereby the shape is created on a layout in Master layout?

**Other notes**

1. If I put `ovalShape` and `pieShape` onto the slide itself (not in
   any Custom Layout), this problem does not happen.
2. Code to update `ovalShape.TextFrame2.TextFrange.Text`

   ```
    //atimer extends System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    //it has a property called ticking that stores the current second

    ovalShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = atimer.ticking.ToString();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint is unreliable about refreshing the SlideShow view when you make changes to slides/masters during a presentation.

Sometimes it's enough to do a .View.GoToSlide(x) where x is the SlideIndex of the current slide.

When that doesn't work, it can help to add a shape on or off slide then delete it.  It might also help to do the gotoslide trick after adding the shape and again after deleting it.